# AFDataResponse : Convert data to JSON format Swift 5

Tags: swift, alamofire

I implemented the following code

```
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseData(completionHandler: {response in

            print(response)

            switch response.result {
            case .success:

                print(response.result)
               let alertVC = self.alertservices.alert(title: "Add Recipe : Basic Level", message: "Your basic level recipe details has been submitted successfully!", cancelTitle: "Cancel", submitTitle: "Ok", alertimage: "recipes"){
                   self.detailContainerView.isHidden = false

               }
               self.present(alertVC,animated: true)

                break
            case .failure :
                let alertVC = self.alertservices.alert(title: "Add Recipe : Basic Level", message: "Something went wrong. Please try again!", cancelTitle: "Cancel", submitTitle: "Ok", alertimage: "recipes"){

                }
                self.present(alertVC,animated: true)
                break
            }
})
```

If I use `.responseData` then I get the this output `success(118 bytes)` instead of what is mentioned below. But the actual response which I get when I place the values in the postman is

```
{
    "response": "success",
    "status": 0,
    "recipe_id": 10422
}
```

If I use `.responseJSON` then the following error is shown at the console.

```
["recipe_preparation_time": "00:10:00", "recipe_title": "test recipe", "recipe_category": "2", "veg_status": "1", "recipe_food_type[]": [1, 3], "type": "3", "recipe_cooking_time": "00:10:00", "recipe_country": "", "customer_id": "5", "added_by": "5", "difficulty_level": "1"]
success({
    error =     {
        "recipe_food_type" =         (
            "The recipe food type field is required."
        );
    };
    message = "Validation Error";
    status = 406;
})
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: the same API format works for android apps.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify exactly what it is you want help with?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Codable resposne struct, and decode using `JSONDecoder()`:

```swift
struct Response: Codable {
    let response: String
    let status, recipeId: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case response, status
        case recipeId = "recipe_id"
    }
}
```

Add this format for you request:

```swift
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseDecodable(of: Response.self) { response in
```

Comment: I am getting an error at `let data = response.responseData` saying unresolved identifier. @Frankenstein

Comment: Same error at `CodableResponse.self`saying unresolved identifier.

Comment: `failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(code: 500)))` this error is shown in the response. @Frankenstein

Comment: Use `Response` the codable struct Name.

Comment: I missed your `POST` parameters check now.

Comment: `failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "response", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"response\", intValue: nil) (\"response\").", underlyingError: nil)))))` . @Frankenstein

Comment: This means the response is not the same as you have given in your question. Check the response on `POSTMAN` app.

Comment: `{
    "response": "success",
    "status": 0,
    "recipe_id": 10423
}` - this is the same response which I have added above

Answer (score 0):

As @Frankenstein mentioned its good to create Codable struct. But when you are using Alamofire you can use:

```
AF.request(url).validate().responseDecodable(of: Response.self) { response in   
  // and then on response.value you have your response struct
}
```